# adding a html row in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable

```
function createNotificTable(callback) {

var tbl = $("#gridNotificInbox tbody");
var empid = $("#hdnempidmaster").val(); //logged in employee
var maxid = 0;
if (parseInt($('#gridNotificInbox tbody tr').length) > 0) {
    maxid = Math.max.apply(Math, $("#gridNotificInbox tbody tr td:first-child").map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }));
}
alert(maxid);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "notification.aspx/ReturnTableRow",
    data: JSON.stringify({ maxidfetched: maxid, empid: empid }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {

    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.d.trim() != "") {
            tbl.prepend(response.d);

            //want to call datatable initialization or restyle here//
        }
        callback();
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        //alert(response.d);
    }

});
```

}

this function is calling a webmethod in asp.net.The webmethod returns a table row structure as 
"<tr><td>....</tr><tr..."

initializeDatatable-is the function to initialize datatable.

```
function initializeDatatable() {
try {
    datatbl= $("#gridNotificInbox").dataTable({
    ordering: false
    });

} catch (ex) {
alert(ex);
}
}
```

Now after prepending row in the table tbody of "gridNotificInbox" how to reflect that it in datatable?I can do for 1st time initialization but after adding row?
If I am in 2nd page of datatable,I want the new row will be added at 1st page as it is prepending,not appending,but I want to stay in 2nd page like gmail.
This code is working not using datatable.But I want paging and searching facility,and that's why I use datatable.

Comment: Have you tried changing the fnDraw callback to false?

Answer (score 0):

```
function initializeDatatable() {
try {
    datatbl= $("#gridNotificInbox").dataTable({
    ordering: false,
    draw : false,
    });

} catch (ex) {
alert(ex);
}
```

Try this one. The table will not redraw automatically and will stay on what page you were at and even the sorting and ordering.